# Customizing joomla menu

Tags: templates, joomla, menu, styles, customization

There is a file megamenu.less and I passed to the point where I can get bigger buttons but I am not able to add color to the buttons and make dropdown look nicer.

What code should I add to my template.less?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to add in your template.css line 2507:

```
nav.zo2-menu .navbar-nav > li > a { padding: 20px; }
```

You also have to add at the end of the file:

```
.nav.navbar-nav.level-top a { background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #72b626 !important; }
```

Good luck!